# How can you get DurationField value in seconds in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which uses Django's DurationField to take inputs from users how long a task might take

```
class Step(models.Model):
    
    stepnumber = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField()
    duration = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
```

when I get query for the duration values, it returns values in HH:MM:SS.

```
>>> steps = Step.objects.all()
>>> for s in steps:
...     print(s.duration)
... 
0:00:00
0:01:00
0:02:00
0:05:00
0:04:00
0:00:05
0:01:00
>>>
```

I want to get these values in seconds. Like instead of 0:01:00, I want to get 60. How can I do that. When I check MySQL database, I see that stores the values in microseconds, but shell query returns in HH:MM:SS format.

-- Beginner in Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve those things using model property like this...

## models.py

```
class Step(models.Model):
    stepnumber = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField()
    duration = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)

    @property
    def duration_in_seconds(self):
        return f"{self.duration.seconds} seconds"
```

## Output in admin panel

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It works for me and I learned a new thing, all thanks to you. I wanted to upvote but I don't have enough reputation...